# E/EGL_emulation error = EGL_BAD_MATCH

Tags: java, android

I have searched several sites and tried every solution suggested even found my exact problem on one site but have never found a solution. I finally gave up and decided to use my personal phone as a test device a Samsung Galaxy S4 running lollipop. The same issue, it is loaded on the phone but then it won't run.

At this point I am wondering if the problem is the code. Even though in a beginner tutorial I am taking the instructor puts these three lines of code in and runs them and they create a simple fade of an image that you can watch run in the video the image loads and when the instructor clicks the image in the emulator it will fade out and disappear. But when I run it I get the following.

> E/EGL_emulation eglsurfaceattrib (EGL_BAD_MATCH) W/OpenGLRender: Failed to set EGL_Swap_Behavior on surface error=EGL_BAD_MATCH

The code is this:

```
public void fade (View view) { 
   ImageView pic1 = (ImageView) findviewById(R.id.pic1);
   pic1.animate().alpha(0f).set Duration(2000); 
}
```

Is there something wrong with this code? The image will load on the emulator at that point you get the error above and the application terminates. On my phone the image will load but tapping it does nothing it just sits there.

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be no space between << fade (View view) { >>  &  << set Duration >>
Also the  << v >>  in  << findViewById >> Should be capital

Try it like this.

```
public void fade(View view) {
   ImageView pic1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic1);
   pic1.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000); 
}
```